# How to print words containing specific letters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have file with words, each line contain a word. What I try do to is ask user for a letters and search for a words with all these letters user has input.
I work on it for a few days but can't make lines 7 and 8 running properly only getting different errors or either is not giving any results.

```
letters = input('letters: ')
words = open('thesewords').read().splitlines()

print (words)
print(".......................")

for word in words:
    if all(letters) in word:
        print(word)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `all()` wrongly.
`all(letters)` is always a `True` for string `letters`, and `True in <string>` returns you a `TypeError`.

What you should do is:

```
all(x in word for x in letters)
```

So, it becomes:

```
for word in words:
    if all(x in word for x in letters):
        print(word)
```

Comment: Yes, I got it now, I was using it wrongly, this was the last one of many others I've done, that way is working thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A more simpler solution if you omit `all` would be:

```py
letters = input('letters: ')
words_in_file = open('thesewords').read().splitlines()

for word in words_in_file:
    if letters in words:
        print(word)
```

Comment: Yes, only if `letters` is a subset of `word`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
letters = input('letters: ')

# Make sure you include the full file name and close the string
# Also, .readlines() is simpler than .read().splitlines()
words = open('thesewords.txt').readlines()

# I'll assume these are the words:
words = ['spam', 'eggs', 'cheese', 'foo', 'bar']

print(words)
print(".......................")

for word in words:
    if all(x in word for x in letters):
        print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the there are a lot of Syntax Error in the code, I am trying to re-write the code which you have provided drawing a rough sketch of your objective. I hope the code below will satisfy your demand.

```
letters = input("letters:" )
words = open("thesewords.txt","r")
for word in line.split():
    print (word)
print(".......................")
for wrd in words:
    if letters in wrd:
        print(wrd)
    else:
        continue
```